# How much current should a car draw from a battery when it is off?

Tags: current, automotive

My SUV died last night, and it draws 540mA now, when the car is off, and nothing (that I know of) is on. How much does a car typically draw from the battery when it is off?

---

EDIT 1:

I think you've already answered my question (half an amp is an unreasonable amount of power draw with the car off), but I would like to give you more information anyway.  I narrowed it down to one fuse, which has a bunch of stuff on it:

BCM, Auto Light & Photo Sensor, Room Lamp, Driver/Passenger Vanity Lamp Switch, Date Link Connector, Door warning Switch, RF Receiver, A/C Control Module, Luggage Lamp, IPS Control Module, Instrument Cluster (IND.), Map Lamp, Electro Chromic Mirror

I am going to assume that "Date Link Connector" is really "**Data** Link Connector".

"IPS Control Module" is also listed under multiple other fuses, and I don't know what that means.  Tried to find out what IPS means, but there is no glossary or abbreviations table, and I'm not sure.

"A/C Control Module" is also listed under multiple other fuses as well.  Not sure what this means either.

---

EDIT 2:

This fuse is part of a two part special assembly called the "Memory Fuse" which apparently is a collection of devices, some having non-volatile memory that gets lost if it is unpowered.  Also, that's where the half amp of power is being drawn from (the second of the two fuses).

Here are some pictures of the assembly (which has two 10-amp fuses) and relevant sections from the manual:

[image: Two part fuse assembly.]

The following portion of the manual explains that some things will not operate if you pull this fuse assembly, namely "warning chime, audio, clock and interior lamps, etc." I like the "etc" part.

It also states that "Some items must be reset after replacement" indicating the non-volatile memory will be lost. I'm assuming audio (radio presets), but don't yet know what else that may mean (perhaps the A/V, which we don't have).

[image: Screen shot of Blurb from manual.]

Here is what the "Memory Fuse" protects, the first fuse for the first section, and the second fuse for the second section (the second fuse is the one drawing the half amp):

[image: Screen shot of "Memory Fuse" portion of manual, the detail about what it covers.]

Comment: According to [this](https://no.co/blog/parasitic-draw) it should be < 100mA.

Comment: Lock the doors and wait a while (maybe ten minutes) then check the current again (with the car still locked.)  The computers and stuff in my car stay active as long as the doors are unlocked.  Leaving the car unlocked in a locked garage for a few days drains the battery to the point that it won't start.  Lock it, give it a chance to "go to sleep," then measure the current again.

Comment: Troubles shoot, disconnect the fuses one after another when you measure the current so you can isolate to what circuit that is drawing the most current.

Comment: @relayman357 that sounds like an overly generic statement. Honestly, I'd expect a modern medium- to upper class car to draw significantly more. There's anti-theft, communication, locking, and quite a few other systems to be kept alive. And a modern battery has say 80 Ah capacity, and a 5% self-discharge per month, that's about 55 mA in self-discharge current, anyway. Assuming a full car would not dare to draw more than twice the self-discharge seems unwarranted, as that has no practical negative effects.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about car characteristics, not about electrical engineering.

Comment: Good points Marcus.  I agree.

Comment: 50mA is generally reckoned to be the maximum draw you'd expect from a car battery when it's parked up. Don't forget the car will be difficult to start long before the battery gets down to 0%. 50mA would take an 80Ah battery down to 50% in about a month.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 5% self-discharge of 80Ah per month would be 5.5mA not 55mA.

Comment: Marcus a wise engineer can re-frame the question into a design engineering question, or is that asking too much of moderators

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 something like [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144640/how-to-measure-the-current-drawn-by-the-radio-and-the-headlights-from-car-batter)

Comment: If you rephrase the question, for instance, "Can I determine what is drawing current when the car is switched off, by for instance pulling each fuse and measuring the current flow across it?".

Comment: I know security add-ons reduce battery lifespan, from a time when our NDP govt owned auto insurance gave out Interruptors free to reduce auto-theft with wireless disable under the hood. The question might be better phrased, what life expectancy can be expected in reduction for higher than normal battery drain of 100mA max. And a new battery of 50Ah or an aged one of 50% . Perhaps too difficult to answer, but possible. But in the old days if an 8W bulb was dim in series with Vbat,that was considered acceptable.

Comment: check the boot lid switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s far too much current and will possibly kill the battery after extended unused periods and a voltage drops below 11.5V when sulphating accelerates.

- a fresh 50Ah battery may be dead after 100h @ 0.5h rate.

Reduce that to <50mA or add a trickle charger and plug in it if you cannot locate or eliminate the TDB load.

Comment: This happened to my generator. The electronics in standby mode draw 0.6A and the trickle charger packed up, causing the battery to discharge so low it wrecked the battery. With a modern SUV you can't simply disconnect the battery because it messes with the computer, so better to fix the fault  or at least keep it on charge.

Comment: Really? Volatile memory settings?

Comment: Yes, volatile memory settings.  And the fuse I narrowed the problem down to (see edit), is part of a special two-part fuse assembly that you are supposed to pull out when not starting the car for a while, so my problem may actually be expected.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 -- My process of narrowing down the problem to the one fuse killed my battery, so it must be as good as dead. Please see "Edit 2" which has pictures and details of the non-volatile fuse assembly, in which I believe you are interested.  And was that a "TBD" load?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 -- I think it's narrowed down to BCM, Date Link Connector, RF Receiver, IPS Control Module, Electro Chromic Mirror.  Any idea what's drawing 500mA?

Comment: Nope, but a current sensor will help you locate it.

Comment: Or maybe the dealer if on warranty but a defective RF might be the only item enabled with IGN. Off for the remote trunk with keyFOB. disconnect that and try again

Comment: But if added the BCM , and it’s a rPi 3 or 4, that’s the culprit when you ought to have considered a PIC or a ZERO (100mA idle)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a 194 bulb is staying on. 194 bulbs draw about .5 amps.

Comment: If it's a fairly new vehicle, the 194 style bulbs are probably LED with much less current draw. The old tungsten bulbs are about 5W. One problem with tungsten bulbs is that they will draw a lot more current if the voltage drops below point of incandescence. Then again, modern cars may use DC-DC switching converters, which also draw more current as voltage is reduced. I would think a modern vehicle would have a low voltage alarm and cut-out, but then that would add 50 cents to the cost, and the bean counters trump the engineers and good reason,,,

Comment: Look at the list of devices powered by the "memory fuse". While it COULD be a single bulb it is more likely to be a mix of the other devices.